How to stop my Azure Machine Learning Batch Jobs registering anonymous data assets in workspace
I am successfully using Azure Machine Learning Batch job as part of an ETL process.
However, an issue I have is that each etl run ends up registering an anonymous data asset to the workspace.
We are currently triggering via rest call, referencing a registered data store
{
  "properties": {
            "InputData": {
                "batchInput": {
                    "JobInputType": "UriFolder",
                    "Uri": "azureml://datastores/<datastore>/paths/<input folder>"
                }
            },
            "OutputData": {
                "batchOutput": {
                    "JobOutputType": "UriFile",
                    "Uri": "azureml://datastores/<datastore>/paths/<output folder>"
                }
            }, 
            "compute": {"instanceCount": "1"}
        }
    }

What I'm looking for support on:

how to stop it registering a data asset

Failing that

give it a consistent name so they are versioned and do not mess up the data asset tab.

the batch_script run function - note that we use the output data to write a parquet file to a registered datastore, rather than use the run functions return output.
def run(mini_batch):

    print(f"run method start: {__file__}, run({mini_batch})")

    for mb in mini_batch:
        df = pd.read_parquet(mb)

        <apply data transformations> 

        parquet_file_path = os.path.join(output_path, Path(mb).stem + '.parquet')
        print(f'parquet_path:{parquet_file_path}')

        SCHEMA = pa.schema([<pa schema>])
        
        df.to_parquet(parquet_file_path, schema=SCHEMA)

    return mini_batch


Because you are giving the batch output for you batch job. You need remove OutputData and alter your batch job script not to register. Add your batch job script.

you say remove the OutputData section? if I wanted to specify an specific output location for the data, wouldn't removing the section cause that?
